# PHP Replace Array with multiple Array by key

Tags: php, arrays

> i have Main Array  and i want to replace

```
Array
(
    [0] => {title-1}
    [1] => zebra
    [2] => {title-1}
    [3] => fruit
    [4] => {title-2}
    [5] => cars
    [6] => {title-3}
    [7] => city
    [8] => {title-3}
    [9] => amazing
    [10] => gold
    [11] => {title-2}
)
```

and then i have 3 array like that

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => Blue
        [2] => Red
    )
    Array
    (
        [6] => lamborghini
        [8] => bugati

    )
   Array (

    [4] => Yellow
    [11] => dodge
)
```

i want to  output like that

```
    (
        [0] => blue
        [1] => zebra
        [2] => red
        [3] => fruit
        [4] => yellow
        [5] => cars
        [6] => lamborghini
        [7] => city
        [8] => bugati
        [9] => amazing
        [10] => gold
        [11] => dodge
    )
```

i try used array_replace_recursive() but only work if one array 
can any body help me

Answer (score 0):

To use array_replace_recursive both array keys should be same. refer to below code.

```
$base = array('0' => '{title-1}', '1' => 'zebra','2'=>'{title-1}','3'=> 'fruit','4' => '{title-2}',5 => 'cars',6 => '{title-3}',7 => 'city');
$tem=array ( 0 => 'Blue', 2 => 'Red' ) ;

$tem1=array (4 => 'Yellow',6 => 'dodge');

$basket = array_replace_recursive($base, $tem);
$basket1 = array_replace($basket, $tem1);
print_r($basket1);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Blue
    [1] => zebra
    [2] => Red
    [3] => fruit
    [4] => Yellow
    [5] => cars
    [6] => dodge
    [7] => city
)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you stated you have 3 array wich do contain values for your main array. There has nothing recoursive to be done.

You can simply use "array-replace":

```
$arrayMain = array(0 => "{title-1}", 1 => "zebra", 2 => "{title-1}");
$arrayReplace = array(0 => "Blue", 2 => "Red");

$finishedArray = array_replace($arrayMain, $arrayReplace);
```

This will give you:

```
array(
    0 => "Blue",
    1 => "zebra",
    2 => "Red",
);
```

You can actually use this to replace multiple array_keys from multiple arrays like array_replace($mainArray, $replaceArray1, $replaceArray2); and so on.

Check the PHP Docs:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php